# When is it useful to __restrict__ this?

Tags: c++, class, restrict

GCC supports writing methods such as

```
void T::fn () __restrict__
```

in the scope of whose bodies, `this` is a restricted pointer. Considering the fact that `__restrict__` is not used in function overload resolution - in which cases is it useful to add this qualification?

Comment: If you understand what this qualifier does, then it becomes self-evident when "it is useful to add this qualification".

Comment: So, [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29884292/509868) doesn't answer your question; why? Maybe you should [edit] your question and clarify it.